# Custom content type on registration form. No node title field

Tags: 7, entities, users

I set my custom content type to show on user registration form. I see cck fields, but I don't see node title field (required field) :(

Could somebody give any advice?

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which modules you used to get what you have so far?

Comment: content profile, cck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Content Profile, I assume you also enabled Content Profile User Registration. In the readme file of Content Profile you'll find:

> - The weight of the profile (configurable at the content profile settings) controls the position
>     of the form elements on the registration page.
> - You may also hide some form elements at the settings. Basically it allows you to hide non-required
>     CCK fields as well as the title. If the title is hidden, it is set to the user's name.
> - For more control over the title use the "Automatic Nodetitles" module, which can be found
>     at http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle. It integrates fine with this module.

This means that you should be able to change the settings (like showing the title field) at `admin/content/node-type/[profile-content-type]/profile`, although I personally like auto_nodetitle to set the title on content profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need title or you want it because form gives you error? Maybe Automatic Nodetitles (http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) can help you? You can use that to have node automatic title like "Profile of [Name] [Surname]" and title will not be required field.